# How to Get Current UserID in Xamarin?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, userid

What is the equivalent of Window's "System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name" for IOS and Android in Xamarin? Is there a platform agnostic operation?

Comment: no, not really.  You can have multiple different accounts associated with different apps/functions, there is no single "user" concept that applies across the device.

Comment: Possibly: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.OS.UserManager.UserName/

Comment: My comment should return the name of the user making the call, but I'm not sure that's what you're asking. If you want a generic user set in $USER variable, that's not a thing with Android.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1058/system-environment-username

Comment: you could consider the google account to be the android equivalent of username, although it is optional for the user to add a google account. In iOS it's the apple account, which is mandatory

Comment: On Android, the API documentation pointed to by Jacob above states "This call is only available to applications on the system image; it requires the MANAGE_USERS permission." Is the MANAGE_USERS permission only available to "admins" of the OS? Can an app be assigned necessary permission?